# Fullcalendar Scheduler 5 programmatically expand resource group

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

iam using fullcalendar-Scheduler 5.2.

How can i expnad or collapse a resourcegroup?
i know the **resourcesInitiallyExpanded** function, but i want to expand/collapse a specific resourceGroup.

i found an example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odNOWZ?editors=0010 but this is for an old version of Fullcalendar.

```
viewRender: function(view) { 
      $('#calendar .fc-divider .fc-cell-text').each(function(index, area_text_el) {
        if (area_text_el.innerText === 'Auditorium A') {
          $(area_text_el).siblings('.fc-expander').click()
        }
      })
```

i will use the **resourceGroupLabelDidMount** hook which gives me this args:

When the above hooks are specified as a function in the form function(arg), the arg is an object with the following properties:

**groupValue**

**el** - the element. only available in resourceGroupLabelDidMount, resourceGroupLabelWillUnmount, resourceGroupLaneDidMount, and resourceGroupLaneWillUnmount

But where can call the click function?

Thanks !

Comment: you need to work you which element is the clickable one and then invoke its click function (either using jQuery or vanilla JS), within the callback function. Same idea as the old example you found, except that possibly the HTML structure may have changed - you need to check that first using your browser's element inspector.

Comment: yes thanks, i researched an saw that the name has changed. And i doesn't know how to call a css function, but after some research i found the 'querySelector'. And now its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i figured it our yesterday (after some try'n error)

this is the way i do it:

```
resourceGroupLabelDidMount:function(info){
  if(info.groupValue === 'Auditorium B'){
             info.el.querySelector('.fc-datagrid-expander')
        .click();
  }
```