# resourceGroupLabelDidMount in Full calendar v4.3.1 not working

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

I want to expand only Particular resource in fullcalendar. So that i used  resourceLabelDidMount

```
     resourceGroupLabelDidMount:function(info){
      console.log("reached");
      if(info.groupValue === 'Doctor){
                 info.el.querySelector('.fc-datagrid-expander')
            .click();
      },
```

But here code is not reaching here. console in not working.I referred
[Fullcalendar Scheduler 5 programmatically expand resource group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375749/fullcalendar-scheduler-5-programmatically-expand-resource-group)

Comment: `resourceGroupLabelDidMount` doesn't exist in fullCalendar version 4 - see the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4#toc. You would need to upgrade to version 5 (or you can try to use the v4 functionality to achieve the same, but I don't think it would be possible). Did it not occur to you to check the v4 documentation when you found you had a problem (especially since you were using an example based on v5)?

Comment: @ADyson Thankyou so much for your valuable feedback. the feature in fullcalendar v4 viewSkeletonRender enabled me to expand the particular resource.

Comment: If that's your solution please add it to the Answers section below...don't hide it in the comments. That way, people will be able to search for it, ready it clearly, and upvote it :-). See the [tour] if you're unsure how stackoverflow works.

Comment: @ADyson Okay, Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The property called viewSkeletonRender enabled to expand particular resource in fullcalndar v4.  

     viewSkeletonRender: function(view){
                $('#calendar .fc-divider .fc-cell-text').each(function(index, area_text_el) {
            if (area_text_el.innerText === 'Doctor') {
                            $(area_text_el).siblings('.fc-expander').click();
                        }
    });
```